# How to call custom field post meta function in array

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I want video link will call custom field

This is my code:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('slider-thumb', array('class' => 'rsImg', 'data-rsvideo' => 'http://www.vimeo.com/61893383' )); ?>
```

My code is:

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('slider-thumb', array('class' => 'rsImg', 'data-rsvideo' => '<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, video, true); ?>' )); ?>
```

There are no syntax errors. But video is not running.

Please help me.

Comment: In second code **My code is:**, how is it possible to add `<?php ... <?php ... ?> ... ?>`.

Comment: You can directly use like this `<?php the_post_thumbnail('slider-thumb', array('class' => 'rsImg', 'data-rsvideo' => get_post_meta($post->ID, video, true) )); ?>` Try like this, it may be work.

Answer (score 4):

You are nesting PHP tags. That's not correct.

And as per the correct syntax in your first example, it accepts a URL.

Let's say your function `get_post_meta($post->ID, video, true);` returns a proper URL, then you can modify your code like this -

```
<?php 
    $myVidURL = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video', true);
    the_post_thumbnail('slider-thumb', array('class' => 'rsImg', 'data-rsvideo' =>  $myVidURL )); 
?>
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to it and for having example good enough to steal, apparently.